# Working flow of autorelease pool

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How AutoReleasePool working in iphone? And when will be the objects released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[At the end of the current iteration of the run loop.](http://parmanoir.com/When_does_autorelease_release_%3F)

Comment: Thanks alex. Can you explain with example? 

If i am using initWithString for NSString,Where it will release the memory?At the end of the method?

Comment: @vinay: You should probably read Apple's Memory Management Guide as this will answer many of your questions: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/memorymgmt.html

Comment: Can you explain how an autorelease pool works at the runtime level.